# How do I grant a Local Windows Service read/write privileges to a single table

Tags: sql-server-2019

I am running a new windows service that I just wrote. Both the service and the sql server are running on the same machine. It can't connect to the sql server. The sql server logs show:

> Login succeeded for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-P9I8PJP$'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: ]

and

> Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-P9I8PJP$'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'JPBPS'. [CLIENT: ]

I can't see a user `WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-P9I8PJP$` for the server or database. But it still connects...

How do I grant a Local Windows Service read/write privileges to a single table?

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand thanks for the comment. I would prefer not to create an extra user on this machine unless I had no alternative. In addition, I don't want to put sql credentials in the service itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46968725/2012419):

```sql
USE JPBPS;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON [cp].[PrintQueue] TO [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
```